# PHP clean URL with no php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is my `.htaccess` code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ movie.php?name=$1
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.in$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.in" [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
```

I need a clean URL for my website.
I've consulted lots of tutorials and forums and created the above code. 
But it's not working. Almost I'm fighting with code.
I don't understand the clean URL concept clearly. Are there any codings I have to write in my PHP file?

```
<a href='movie.php?name=titanic'> Titanic </a>
```

I have this link in my `index.php` file.

I'd like `example.in/movie/titanic` when I click on the link "Titanic".

Also I'd like to get the value by `$_[request]`.

What exactly do I have to do? Please don't mark this question as duplicate, I've searched a lot and haven't got the concept clearly. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. You have double `RewriteEngine On`; 2. Turn this `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ movie.php?name=$1` into this `RewriteRule ^movie/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ movie.php?name=$1`. Now you can get the movie name from `$_GET['name']`.

Comment: Put SEO url in href, not old url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your `.htaccess` into main Directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^movie/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/)$ movie.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Or in `movies/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On /movies/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/)$ ../movie.php?name=$1 [L]
```

While `movie.php` is in main Directory located.

`RewriteEngine On` can by starterd only once per htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

The rules in `.htaccess` work on url's relative to the directory your `.htaccess` file is in. If you have a `.htaccess` in your www-root, then the first argument of RewriteRule will match everything behind the domain name and before the query string (`movie/titanic` in `http://example.com/movie/titanic?is=amovie`). To fix the rule, you need to change the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^movie/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ movie.php?name=$1 [L,NC]
```

The `[L]` flag stops rewriting for this round, the `[NC]` flag ignores case.

Besides that, you only need one `RewriteEngine on`, which needs to be above all rules you write. You can safely delete the second one.